# React Native carousel Preventing flashlist scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my Flashlist, the carousel which is inside the carditem seems to pevent scroll down when the touch happens inside it. I would like to make the flashlist to scroll even when the user touches inside the card item which has a carousel inside it

```
  return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.top}>
          <TopBar pageName="Experiences" />
        </View>
        <View style={{ height: '90%', width: Dimensions.get("screen").width }}>
        <FlashList
        
          data={Viewpoints }
          estimatedItemSize={50 * 3}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <CardItem
              Id={item.Id}
              Storename={item.viewpoint}
              Class={item.classification}
              svg={item.url}
              userImage={item.userImage}
              userName={item.userName}
              PostText={item.PostText}
              Content_audience={item.Content_audience}
              // onPress={(selectedItemId) => {
              //   setSelectedId(selectedItemId); // Update selectedId state
              //   fetchAds(); // Trigger fetchAds function
              // }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />

        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>

  );
```

I tried implementing panresponders and panhandlers but it does not seem to work

How can I solve this problem, below is the carditem

```
const CardItem: FC<CardItemProps> = () => {

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
        const { dx, dy } = gestureState;
        return Math.abs(dy) > 5 && Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx);
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        const { dx, dy } = gestureState;
        if (Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx)) {
          return false;
        }
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
      },
    })
  ).current;  
  return (
    <View style={styles.card} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
      <Carousel                 
        width={350}
        loop={false}
        data={svg}
        withAnimation={{
          type: "spring",
          config: {
            damping: 13,
          },
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Image source={{ uri: item }} style={styles.backgroundImage}/>
        )} />
    </View>
  );
};
```